# How to set an empty label on Material-UI V5 (@mui/lab) datepicker component?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm working on migrating `material-ui` v4 to `MUI` v5 and I was using `material-ui-pickers` along with it.

I read the migration guide: https://mui.com/guides/pickers-migration/ and the docs, but I can't find and equivalent for the `emptyLabel` feature in: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker

`emptyLabel` on `material-ui-pickers` allowed you to set a custom text, that showed up when the value on the picker was set to `null`.

Is this a missing feature in `MUI`'s date picker or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`KeyboardDatePicker` is no longer maintained and is now part of the lab components in MUI v5 as `DatePicker` (as explained in migration guide).

Actually there's no "emptyLabel" prop for `DatePicker` but you can achieve the same effect using the `label` prop and a check on your `value` provided to `DatePicker`:

```
<DatePicker
  label={value === null ? "null value!" : "placeholder"}
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

[see example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6bgu1?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve my issue. I need to place a custom string where the value would be, not the label. It'd be weird to intentionally remove such a feature so my guess is that it's either missing, or it's not been documented how to achieve this.

Comment: I didn't found anything related to a such prop in the [sources](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-lab/src/DatePicker/DatePicker.tsx) so your first guess is correct, but why this behavior cannot be reproduced with simple checks like `value={value || emptyLabelValue}`?

Comment: It's a good question. I tried but it's not possible with `material-ui-pickers` nor with the latest version in MUI. If you pass a string it does not show up. I'm guessing it validates getting a date as value and if not it's ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't using `placeholder` cover your desired use case?

```
<DatePicker
  ...
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      inputProps={{
        ...params.inputProps,
        placeholder: "Place for extra info"
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Here is a live [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/placeholder-mui-v5-xtnzz5?file=/demo.tsx).